# UIAlertView not showing

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I have a small problem with one of my UIAlertViews. I'm trying to show it, do some tasks, and then dismiss automatically. This is the code I'm using currently:

```
callingTaxi = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"検索中" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[callingTaxi show];
/* Do some tasks */
[callingTaxi dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
[callingTaxi release];
```

However, the UIAlertView only shows half-way. I can see the background darken, but then after the tasks have completed, the alert view quickly appears and then disappears, again.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Ben

Comment: can you elaborate on your solution as I have the same problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does show, but you dismiss it right away, instead of waiting for the user to do something, with

```
[callingTaxi dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

There is no time for iOS to render it completely. Anyway, this is not how dismissWithClickedButtonIndex is supposed to be used.  What are you trying to achieve here?

Edit: I guess you need to assign a delegate to the UIAlertView, and let the delegate handle what happens inside the AlertView.

Comment: can you explain more what you mean by "the delegate handle what happens inside the AlertView"

Comment: @Rasman: Take a look at http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uialertview/ which explains how you can create a UIAlertViewDelegate in order to handle button clicks from a UIAlertView

Answer (score 1):

You should not close it inside the same function which shows it, close it by timer, or as reaction to another event.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a delegate. The problem is that the tasks you do must happen on a background thread, so the main thread is left alone to update the screen.

If you update your code to use blocks and dispatch queues, everything will work:

```
callingTaxi = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"検索中" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[callingTaxi show];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL), ^{
    /* Do some tasks */
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // this code is back on the main thread, where it's safe to mess with the GUI
        [callingTaxi dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        [callingTaxi release];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create a method for the alertview

```
- (void) alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
// Do stuff
// Or if you have multiple buttons, you could use a switch

[callingTaxi release];
```

Or you could Autorelease..

But x3ro has given the correct answer, you call the method yourself instead of waiting for the user to press the button..

Answer (score 0):

the uialertview is dismissed by:
        [callingTaxi dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
before the user can read it.

How long do you intend to have the end user read it???