# Convert URL string to image fast in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, url, nsstring, uiimage

I need to convert an URL string to UIImage.
I'm currently using the following code:

```
NSString *stringEncodingUrl = [[[ourWorkIcon objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Pic_s"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSURL *Imageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:Imageurl]; 
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];`
```

but this takes a very long time.
So my question is: how to convert the URL to an image faster?

Comment: Check this link [Asynchronous function][1] It's just perfect.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225532/asynchronous-function-execution

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no you can't.

Long answer: loading an image (which is, tipically, a relatively large file) from a web server is an expensive and slow operation, and you don't really have control over the transfer speed/bandwidth of the network.

Comment: To expand on this, you will need to work asynchronously and load your data in the background. When the data becomes available, you will then need to update your UI with it. This is the only way to deal with loading images while maintaining responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

H2CO3 is right. You can only minimize the impact by doing it in the background (so the delay doesn't block your entire UI ... images just take a little time to appear) and caching the images locally for future use (thus, check to see if you've already downloaded it before you try to retrieve it again).